# Apache Camel Event Notifier for log component

Tags: logging, event-handling, apache-camel

I created an event notifier in camel and attached it to camel Context. It works fine by logging my message for endpoints only.

is there a way of writing Custom EventNotifier for components like
.log() in camel route??

Comment: What do you mean, can you explain better?

Comment: Sorry for writing so small.... If my camel route                      from("direct:start")
.bean(FlakyProcessor.class).log("MyLogger:Message").to("mock:result");    The .log() component automatically should invoke the MyEventNotifier....

Comment: That is not possible the event notifier is mainly about exchange sending events, not calling the log. You can add your own processor that send the events and do the logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this solution could be out of Box, however it has worked for me.

Log is an EIP, you can either get the eip within the context from Exchange Properties, or from the MessageHistory, with the help of little logic you can achieve it to get control over the Event notifier.. Hope it helps..! [check this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894057/restrict-event-notifier-for-multicast-eip)