# restrict event notifier for multicast eip

Tags: event-handling, apache-camel

Is it possible to know whether any Eip has been used in my context, a unique id or something like that..!

When exchange is copied , for each copies Event is notified, is there any possibility to restrict it to notify once..

Ref: Used and tested with the Apache Camel "MultiCast" eip

Comment: This is a bit too generic to figure out what you are asking about can you provide a code sample?  right now it almost sounds like 2 separate questions

Comment: You should post the solution so others can see. SO is also about giving back to the community.

Comment: sorryy, added.. I was a lil busy on my project...

Comment: added the answer below, can you please up vote it, if its correct..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1: Eip - Multicast will be available in the CamelExchange properties... as CamelMulticastIndex.
2: Eip - WireTap, will be available in Camel MessageHistory(InOnly) pattern...

Hope it helps in solving ...

Comment: Had the same problem, thank you so much, its working for me now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign id's to any processor or endpoint in camel. Would that help ?

Comment: What do you mean EIP ? Choice, Multicast, Splitter and all right ? If yes, you can certainly assign id's

Comment: can you please share an example to assign id for the multicast, it looks a lil promising by the way, if it is possible..!!